# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql-server, asp.net

tengo un problema con la propiedad length, lo que intento hacer es extraer unos datos de la base de datos cargarlos en ajax y luego por una funcion creo un html que me los datos en formato de carousel. Pero por el momento la funcion addRow3() me esta tirando problemas por el length. Adjuntare unos fragmentos del codigo.

asi obtengo los datos en ajax

```
function sendDataAjax3() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Index.aspx/CumpleHoy",
        datosdata: {},
        contentType: 'application/json; chartset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status + " \n" + xhr.responseText, "\n" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (datos2) {
            addRow3(datos2);
            console.log(datos2);

        }
    });
}
```

en addRow3(datos2) estoy cargándole la data que obtuve de ajax a una funcion, adjunto la funcion

```
function addRow3(datos2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < datos2.length; i++) {
        tabla2 = $('<div style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center"><h3>Feliz Cumpleaños</h3>');
        $("#carousel2").append(tabla2);   
    }
}
```

en tabla2 generaría una "pantalla" por cada dato que se haya extraído del ajax y lo pondria en el html
por ultimo, adjuntare el html.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div id="carousel2" class="carousel-item active">
      <!--DataAjax-->                          
   </div>
</div>
```

Ojalas se entienda mi problema, trate de ser lo mas especifico posible, cualquier ayuda la agradecería mucho.

Comment: Ehh, bueno, `datos2` vine como undefined desde success. Revisa que `Index.aspx/CumpleHoy` te esté retornando lo que corresponde

Comment: Justo iba a comentar lo mismo

Comment: Lo unico que puedo pensar por ahora es que no estas obteniendo nada por parte del servidor, por eso obtienes el error, ya que tu creo que tu codigo esta bien.